# inverse trigonometric functions with plus minus sign

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

$$  \cos\left(\theta_{} \right) =  \pm  \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  $$

$$  \theta_{} = \pm \cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right)       $$

I can't get why the leftmost $~ \pm  ~$ of the right term of the second equation should be needed?

I thought as

$$  \cos\left(\theta_{} \right) =  \pm  \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   } ~~ $$

is held,

$$  \theta_{} = \cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right)       $$

must be held.

misprint?

---

Comment: Note that $\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$.

Comment: Ah, I may got the conception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  \cos\left(\theta_{} \right) =  \pm  \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }   $$

$$  \theta_{} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{constant angle }  $$

As this argument is thrown to the cosine function ,the 2 way return values exist and it are $~ \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  ~$

$$  \theta_{} =  \cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right)       $$

$$  \cos\left(\cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right) \right) = \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  $$

By the way,

$$  \theta_{} = - \cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right)       $$

$$  \cos\left(-\cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right) \right)  $$

$$ = \cos\left(\cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right) \right)  =  \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  $$

$$  \therefore ~~ \theta_{} = \pm \cos^{-1} \left( \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  \right) \ni \cos\left(\theta_{} \right) = \pm \frac{  1  }{  \sqrt{ 3 }   }  $$